# How to Add a UITextfield on top of pinch to zoom image

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Trying to add a UITextfield on top of pinch to zoom image. I was able to get the pinch to zoom on an image working but adding the UITextField is where I'm getting stuck. I'm trying to get the UITextField to stay on specific part of an image when zooming in/out of the image. I thought I was getting close but it seems Xcode is not liking the constraints I added to the UITextfield. Thx for the help.

Current code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ZoomImage: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    private var textField: UITextField {
        let ut = UITextField()
        ut.backgroundColor = .black
        return ut
    }
    
    // create scrollView
    private let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let sv = UIScrollView()
        sv.backgroundColor = .red
        return sv
    }()
    
    // create imageView
    private var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.backgroundColor = .blue
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
    }
    
    func setup() {
        // Allows us to have this view be the delegate of the textfield
        self.textField.delegate = self
        // Allows us to have this view be the delegate of the scrollview
        scrollView.delegate = self
        // add Scrollview to view
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        // Defining imageView
        let image = UIImage(named: "test.png")!
        imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: image.preferredPresentationSizeForItemProvider)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.addSubview(textField)
        
        //Defining Textfield
        textField.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: image.preferredPresentationSizeForItemProvider)
        textField.placeholder = "TEsting"
        
        // add UIImageView to scroll view
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        scrollView.addSubview(textField)
        
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // respect safe-area
        let safeG = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // Zoom range
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0
        
        // constraints
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor),
            
            textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
            textField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0)
            
        ])
    }
}

extension ZoomImage:  UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting the text field's constraints to be relative to the image view instead of the scrollview? And why is the text field being made the full size of the scroll view?

Comment: Hello, I did originally, but ended up getting this error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10) on the NSLayoutConstraint line

Comment: It's not clear what your goal is. How exactly do you want the text field to be sized and positioned as the image view is zoomed in and out?

Comment: I just noticed that you first add the textfield to the image view and you then add the textfield to the scrollview. Pick one.

Comment: As for sizing I was planning for it to be fixed. Now for the position, if I were to put the Textfield on the top right corner of the image I would want the text field to stay in that position of the image whether I zoom in/out. let me know now if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to fix a few serious bugs in your code.

1. Change `textField` so it only ever creates one instance. Your code was creating a new `UITextField` instance every time the `textField` property was referenced. Make it like the other view properties:

   ```swift
   private let textField: UITextField = {
       let ut = UITextField()
       ut.backgroundColor = .gray
       return ut
   }()
   ```
2. Don't try to add the text field to two different superviews. Remove the line:

   ```swift
   imageView.addSubview(textField)
   ```
3. Don't create a new `UIImageView` instance. Replace the line:

   ```
   imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
   ```

   with:

   ```
   imageView.image = image
   ```
4. You are using constraints. Don't bother setting view frames. Remove any lines that set the `frame` property of any view.

The next thing is to update the scroll view constraints to make use of `frameLayoutGuide` and `contentLayoutGuide`. Then anchor the text field to the top/trailing corner of the content.

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
    scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
    scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
    scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.topAnchor, constant: 0),

    imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
    imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0),

    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor),
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.heightAnchor),

    textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
    textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0),
])
```

With all of that in place you can initially see the full image and the text field is in the upper-right corner. But as you zoom the image, the text field stays at the top but it doesn't move to the right as expected. If you scroll all the way to the left then the text field appears at the right edge of the screen, but not the right edge of the image view.

This issue can be solved by updating the constraints of the text field as the scroll view's zoom level changes.

Add the following additional scroll view delegate method:

```swift
func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
    textField.removeFromSuperview()
    scrollView.addSubview(textField)
    let xC = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.textField, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: scale, constant: 0)
    let yC = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.textField, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide, attribute: .top, multiplier: scale, constant: 0)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        xC,
        yC,
    ])
}
```

This ensures the text field is positioned correctly at the end of each zoom (in or out).

---

This seems like a UIKit bug to me. The `contentLayoutGuide` doesn't seem to be updated as the content is zoomed. There should be no need to manually apply the `scale` to the contraint's `multiplier`.

---

I tried an alternate approach of adding the text field directly to the image view and setting the text field's constraints relative to the image view. That worked without any extra code except the text field's size also changed along with the image view. Since the goal is to keep the text field its original size, that wasn't going to work. Applying a "scale" transform to the text field made it easy enough to get it to be the desired size but that caused a shift in its a position a bit. I gave up trying to get constraints working while applying various transforms to the view.

Comment: This worked perfectly! This was more complicated than I thought thx!

Comment: Glad it helped. It was harder than it should have been. Also note I just added steps 3 and 4 to the answer. You had two other issues I forgot to write up initially.